# Unable to create a mongoid query with model name in the GET parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

my query in mongoid

```
model_name = params[:state].classify.constantize
@result = model_name.find(:name => params[:name])
```

the above code doesn't work i get a error **wrong constant name California**  where as the code below works

```
@result = California.find(:name => params[:name])
```

My model_name variable consists of the data "California"
which a model in my project. I want to query my db based on the parameters that come in. How to go about this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you posting the exact error message? Here's what I get

```
'california'.classify # => "Californium"
```

I bet you don't have `Californium` model :)

Comment: Thanks. I had a model name California instead of californium